# Open WIA Scanner Settings Menu (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wia

I have to do a pop-up menu to manage the WIA scanner properties like Resolution, Zoom, Color, etc..

I was wondering if there is any default settings menu that I could use to set the WIA properties and then scan a document.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Assuming you have added the WIA component as a COM Reference, you get a property as `WIA.Property property = [Current Scanner Item].Properties.get_Item(ref "The Property Index")`, then set it as `property.set_Value(ref [The Property Value]);` -- For example, the Scan resolution DPI index is `"6147"`. The `[Current Scanner Item]` is the `WIA.Item` (an `IItem` object) that references the current Device.

Comment: The best way is to create a Form_Load method and put initial setting in the load method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.